# Use version control system as part of application

Tags: javascript, git, web-applications, version-control, bitbucket

I'm student working on senior project on reference manager software on html5 and version control is one of the fucntions. I think i will use bitbucket as part of my website. My target users is people who's not familiar with IT so i want system that user can use VCS functions without going to github or bitbucket.

My question is can i write a command to connect my website with bitbucket with one bitbucket account and user can use VCS function through my system. My system will create repo for each user for their work on my website and they'll never know the process behind this website that was run by bitbucket.

Comment: why don't you host your website online so that anybody can access without hassle?

Comment: Definitely! you can do that see this https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/

Comment: I am a bit wondering wht do you mean by "they'll never know the process behind this website..." If you are going to issue requests to bitbucket from your client, then users will be able to see the requests in the network. Only way to hide the fact that you are going to use bitbucket is to serve all the requests from your server, and to forward those to bitbucket from server-side.